# selecting data from two tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I am using hibernate to create these two tables.
    I have tables like `student(id, username, loginame)` and another table like `class(id, classname, studentname)`

Here my common column is that in student table *username* and in class table *studentname*.

Now my question is that how can I select

`id, username and classname`

from these two tables.

**Note:**

1. My column names need be same like that don't give suggestion like change your column names please.
2. I don't have any relation between these two tables. If I have I can use joins. The only relation I have is that I am storing name in student.username and class.studentname.
3. I am using postgresql 8.4.

For more details you can check this link

> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22703/how-can-i-get-data-from-two-tables/22719#22719.

That's my basic problem. If I achieve this (posting issue) using two tables without joining each other, then I can easily get my expected result.

Comment: Is this homework? It's OK if so, it's just best to say so.

Comment: If you're insistent on not using a join, you probably need a subquery.

Comment: Thank for understanding my problem, now how can i wrote a subquery, can u help to me. i hope you might have seen my **sub query** too in the prescribed URL.

Comment: Hang on, are you asking for SQL answers, or hibernate HQL? If this is about Hibernate, try adding your entity classes or mappings.

Comment: I am using **Hibernate and PostgreSQL** . Above ** link**  i explained plainly my problem how my Hibernate classes are the values being store in that two tables things like that. can u check please.

Comment: I tried all possible ways to get the result using query, but i couldn't figure it out, any way finally i used my mobile.mobile_no, then i compared each another using aribaweb(that my frame work) and got the result. `Thank` for your valuable time and co-operation to learn many things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a normal join between studant and class.

Something like

```
SELECT  s.id, 
        c.id, 
        s.username, 
        c.classname          
FROM    student s INNER JOIN              
        class c ON s.username = c.studentname
```

Have a look at

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/bff7e/2/0)

Comment: I am **sorry** i didn't explain my issue clearly first time. can u check my issue now. I just edited my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student.id, student.username, class.classname 
    FROM student LEFT JOIN class ON username = studentname;
```

Comment: I am **sorry** i didn't explain my issue clearly first time. can u check my issue now. I just edited my issue.

Comment: Still I don't see why a join won't help? Could you explain?

Comment: Basically I am using Hibernate classes, if we have java reference then only we can join each of them other wise Hibernate will throw an Exception saying "PATH is EXPECTED." so thats why in my case join wont work.